# Windows 10 doesn't recognize USB MP3 Player

Tags: windows-10, usb, mp3, dlna

I just received this MP3 player, connected it to my Windows 10 PC through USB but it's not recognized by the system (e.g. I can't see the drive in "This PC").

Hope it's ok to post a link here, it's not an ad:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002822577602.html

Randomly, for a couple of minutes every time there's a "HG1262a DLNA Server" appearing and disappearing. I clicked through and saw some relevant folders inside like "All Music". But it wasn't possible to copy files to any of these folders - the file icon was grayed out while dragging and had an "X" icon on it.

I've enabled "Media Streaming" following this guide: https://thegeekpage.com/enable-disable-dlna-server/ but it didn't change anything.

I've also tried re-scanning USB devices in the Device Manager and clicking "Update Driver" on all USB ports. No effect.

I'm out of ideas. How do I connect to this device? (Also messaged the seller but got no response).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Dumb question: Did you inserted a microSD card?

Comment: My guess is its broken or never worked.  Buying a MP3 player for $1 from aliexpress is not the best of ideas.

Comment: @Keltari Price is average for the product and they do work. They DON'T have any internal memory though and the total absence of any mention of the microSD being used makes me think there isn't any (and the "DLNA" is a red herring, it has nothing to do with this device, it's something somewhere else in the network). Without the microSD this is detected like any other (empty) SD card reader, i.e., it should appear in devices but not in file explorer obviously.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Not a dumb question at all!!! I'm the dumb here :) Thought the SD was optional and not THE drive itself. As for the price and cheap colorful stuff - my excuse is it's for the kids, instead of buying them a smartphone :) Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As per @ChanganAuto 's comment - the Micro SD *is* the drive, not inner storage. You have to insert it (not included) in order for the drive to be mounted.